# Whats wrong with this mssql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
Create Procedure ssp_InsertClientDefaults(
@cid int
)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ClientTermData
  (ClientID, TermID, NormCount, NormProb, DiscCount, DiscProb, Weight) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 
   @cid, GlobalTermData.TermID, GlobalTermData.NormCount, GlobalTermData.NormProb, 
   GlobalTermData.DiscCount, GlobalTermData.DiscProb, GlobalTermData.Weight 
   FROM GlobalTermData, DefaultTerms 
  WHERE DefaultTerms.TermID = GlobalTermData.TermID);
END
GO
```

I'm getting an error by 'Where'. I can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might have meant was this:

```
Create Procedure ssp_InsertClientDefaults
(
        @cid int
    )
AS
        BEGIN
            Insert into ClientTermData(ClientID,TermID,NormCount,NormProb,DiscCount,DiscProb,Weight) 
                Select @cid, GlobalTermData.TermID, GlobalTermData.NormCount, 
                   GlobalTermData.NormProb,GlobalTermData.DiscCount,GlobalTermData.DiscProb,
                    GlobalTermData.Weight 
                from GlobalTermData
                Where not exists( Select 1 
                                  from GlobalTermData INNER JOIN DefaultTerms 
                                  on DefaultTerms.TermID = GlobalTermData.TermID
                                  where DefaultTerms.TermID = GlobalTermData.TermID
                                -- And possibly some other exclusion filter using @cid here
                    );
        END
GO
```

**Edit**

*Explanation* - as others have pointed out, you can't return 'select' columns from a where clause back to the insert this way. Also, the exists function can check for just about anything at all - no need to put all the columns in the exists. And lastly, more of a style issue, but it is preferable to do an inner join rather than a cross join with a where join condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but aren't you missing a `VALUES ('foo','bar')` portion of your insert after the `INSERT INTO (derp,cookies)`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a value list - you cannot have a where clause be the value list for a insert statement. You need a select statement. Your query should be something like this:

```
Create Procedure ssp_InsertClientDefaults( 
@cid int 
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
Insert into ClientTermData(ClientID,TermID,NormCount,NormProb,DiscCount,DiscProb,Weight) 
select [something] from [table]
Where not exists( Select @cid,GlobalTermData.TermID,GlobalTermData.NormCount,GlobalTermData.NormProb,GlobalTermData.DiscCount,GlobalTermData.DiscProb,GlobalTermData.Weight from GlobalTermData,DefaultTerms where DefaultTerms.TermID = GlobalTermData.TermID); 

END 
GO
```

Also, don't forget that your select value list must match your insert into statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `WHERE` clause that way. Check MSDN for [INSERT..INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) sintax

You should do something like:

```
INSERT your_table(your_columns)
SELECT your_values
  FROM other_table
 WHERE your_where_conditions
```